# Add class "active" to the div container pagination when auto slide, prev & next

Tags: jquery

Created a carousel using slide JS with custom pagination (Div container like thumbnail). On click function works fine by getting background image slide index value and pagination value. Based on that "active" class added to the "carousel-thumb--content".

Issue here. Auto slide, prev & next - Background slide works fine. But "active" class not adding to the current visible slide. Can any one please suggest how to get "index-value" of visible slide and add class name to the same index value "thumb nail container"

Thanks

**HTML:**

```
<div class="content--carousel">
 <div class="slidesjs-container">
  <div class="slides-item slidesjs-slide" slidesjs-index="0">
    <a href="#">
        <div class="textbox">
            <h1>Architecto, placeat, saepe, delectus.</h1>
            <p>Tenetur, quos, quod inventore animi similique voluptas maiores corrupti sit
                explicabo laudantium delectus cum nihil assumenda?</p>
        </div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/960x400" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="slides-item slidesjs-slide" slidesjs-index="1">
    <a href="#">
        <div class="textbox">
            <h1>Architecto, placeat, saepe, delectus.</h1>
            <p>Tenetur, quos, quod inventore animi similique voluptas maiores corrupti sit
                explicabo laudantium delectus cum nihil assumenda?</p>
        </div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/960x400" />
    </a>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="carousel-thumb">
  <div class="carousel-thumb--content active">
    <a href="#" class="custom-item" data-item="0">
     <div class="carousel-thumb--image">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/63x63">
     </div>
     <div class="carousel-thumb--text">
        <div class="carousel-thumb--title">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
        <div class="carousel-thumb--desc">Ut fringilla augue eget quam lacinia</div>
     </div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="carousel-thumb--content">
   <a href="#" class="custom-item" data-item="1">
    <div class="carousel-thumb--image">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/63x63">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-thumb--text">
        <div class="carousel-thumb--title">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
        <div class="carousel-thumb--desc">Ut fringilla augue eget quam lacinia</div>
    </div>
   </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$('.custom-item').click(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 $('.carousel-thumb--content').removeClass('active');
 $(this).parent().addClass('active');
 $('a[data-slidesjs-item=\'' + $(this).attr('data-item') + '\']').trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: i don't see any like `data-slidesjs-item` and can you provide a `jsfiddle`?

Comment: Hi.. i used below link as reference https://gist.github.com/schadeck/5954646/download#  .. here they dont have addclass "active" method. this is additional based on requirement.